# Transform World data from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system

I have tried different open source tools to transform a world data shapefile from [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) to [EPSG:3857](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857) but I always have an error. I'm not sure, but is it because of Antarctica?

I have tried with GDAL and QGIS and both are unable to do it. Why is it so complicated and how to do it?

The .prj is:

`GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

Comment: Can you open the .prj file and copy the contents of the file into your question field. It may be that your data is whacked. (I would put this in the comment field, but stackexchange doesn't let me do that with low rep. stupid feature of this site)

Comment: I copied it in the edit

Comment: ok, that's totally not the problem.  Sorry :/

Comment: What error are you seeing, and how are you going from 4326 to 3857? You have to treat WGS84 as a spheroid with no flattening (not an ellipsoid) to get the "correct" Mercator XY coordinates.

Comment: the file can be found here: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip maybe you could try to transform it to 3857 or 900913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Mercator projection is usually bound for aereas between 85.0511° North and South.

If your data includes 90° North or South, the reprojection is mathematically not possible.

See also http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames for all kinds of lat/lon to Google Mercator conversions.

Comment: thats right, the data bounds are +-90 North and South. But why is not possible to transform it in Mercator if the North and South extends infinitely in this proj. see: http://www.radicalcartography.net/?projectionref

Comment: 3857 is not Google Mercator... its 900913

Comment: EPSG:3857 and OpenLayers:900913 are equivalent definitions that are describing the internal projected CRS used by Google Maps, Bing Maps, etc.

Comment: Have you ever noticed in Google Maps that you can drag the map North and South indefinately?

Comment: Do you mean east and west? If I zoom out in Google maps (not Google Earth), and scroll north or south far enough I see the data cut-off around 85N and 85S.

Comment: You can drag north of 85.0511, but the coordinates remain just below 90°. QGIS is not able to do a reprojection of 90° North/South because tan(90°) is undefined.

Comment: The data no but the frame of the map can be draggued north and south

Comment: Yes, but never reaching 90° North/South.